# convert XML to equivalent groovy config

Tags: xml, groovy, configuration-files

I have some test config in an  XML doc like this:

```
<WapRules>
    <WapRule>
        <RuleTypeId>1</RuleTypeId>
        <IsExact>false</IsExact>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>gmail</Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </WapRule>
    <WapRule>
        <RuleTypeId>2</RuleTypeId>
        <IsExact>false</IsExact>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>test</Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </WapRule>
    <WapRule>
        <RuleTypeId>2</RuleTypeId>
        <IsExact>true</IsExact>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>srs</Keyword>
            <Keyword>sample</Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </WapRule>
</WapRules>
```

I want to represent this as a [groovy config](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) and then slurp it in.

"WapRules" is a list of "WapRule" elements, so I tried to map this to a [Config.groovy file](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) like this:

```
wap_rules = [
    {
        rule_type_id = 1
        is_exact = false
        keywords = ["gmail"]
    },
    {
        rule_type_id = 2
        is_exact = false
        keywords = ["test"]
    },
    {
        rule_type_id = 2
        is_exact = true
        keywords = ["srs", "sample"]
    }
]
```

and now I slurp in the config and try to access the elements:

```
def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config)
println cfg.wap_rules[0].rule_type_id
```

but the output just has this: `[:]`

So how can I access the members inside `cfg.wap_rules[0]` ? Is there something wrong with my mapping of XML structure to Config.groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. I wasn't mapping the XML document properly.

Here's how I should have written my Config.groovy:

```
wap_rules = [
    [
        rule_type_id : 1,
        is_exact : false,
        keywords : ["gmail"]
    ],
    [
        rule_type_id : 2,
        is_exact : false,
        keywords : ["test"]
    ],
    [
        rule_type_id : 2,
        is_exact : true,
        keywords : ["srs", "sample"]
    ]

]
```

`wap_rules` is now a list of maps, and each map's elements can be accessed easily.

Now I can indeed do `println cfg.wap_rules[0].rule_type_id` and the output is indeed `1`

I guess I was too conditioned by JSON representation (i.e. "I need a list of JSON objects, each one in braces {}") when I wrote the erroneous Config.groovy.

I hope this helps someone else.